# In C#, from a List<Parent> that is actually full of Children, how do I access the specific constructor of those children?

Tags: c#, types, constructor

To start, I have something like this:

```
class Parent
{

    int x;

    public Parent(int _x)
    {
        x = _x
    }
}

class Child1: Parent
{
    int y;

    public Child1(int _y):base(_y)
    {
        y=_y;
    }
}

class Child2: Parent
{
    int z;

    public Child2(int _z):base(_z)
    {
        z=_z;
    }
}
```

A simple parent-child hierarchy. Then, I have a List which is actually full of Child1 and Child2. I want to make copies of each object in the list, and I want to start by making a new item that will be the copy.

But, if I do this:

```
foreach(Parent p in list)
dictionaryOfCopies.Add(p, new Parent(p.x));
```

then the dictionary will be full of Parent's, not Children1 and Children2. Is there a way to invoke the constructor of an object that is typed as its parent type without knowing the specific type of the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be to implement the [`ICloneable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Y0) on your objects, and let each instance clone itself.

```
class Parent : ICloneable
{
    int x;    
    public Parent(int _x)
    {
        x = _x
    }

    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        return new Parent(x);
    }
}

class Child1 : Parent
{
    int y;

    public Child1(int _y) : base(_y)
    {
        y = _y;
    }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        return new Child1(y);
    }
}

class Child2 : Parent
{
    int z;

    public Child2(int _z) : base(_z)
    {
        z = _z;
    }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        return new Child2(z);
    }
}
```

Then, you would use it like so:

```
foreach(Parent p in list)
{
    dictionaryOfCopies.Add(p, p.Clone() as Parent);
}
```

---

To be the devil's advocate, one of the criticisms I've seen of the `ICloneable` interface is that it's not type-safe. If that's irksome to you, you can still take the same idea, but implement your own version of the `Clone` method that returns `Parent` instead of `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Clone Method to Parent that is overridden in each child class. That would allow you to call

```
dictionaryOfCopies.Add(p, p.Clone());
```